# Facebook application development starter question

Tags: facebook

I am a new facebook application deverloper.
I followed this tutorial:http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/video_facebook_quick_start.html

but I have one question is that,the tutor mentioned "Facebook Library downloaded from the GoogleCode page",I searched through the Facebook Developer Pages,but couldn't find such a library (but I could find the Graphs API).

Could anyone experienced show me where to get this library(I am using Adobe FlashBuilder4 to write the application),and do I need more libraries to write an application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article is based on the old "REST API", which is while still working, is deprecated and I wouldn't recommend using it.

You're going to want to focus on using the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), which has replaced the older API. They don't list an ActionScript SDK, but given how easy the new API is to access RESTfully, I can't there's a whole lot you need that would even require an SDK.

Comment: Thanks Dainel!Does that imply I should be good to go with just the Graph API in my FlashBuilder?thx